# How to make short this code, and fix nested populate in Nest JS / Mongoose

Tags: typescript, mongoose, nestjs

Can this code be automated? Because I will have a lot of nested subComments.

```
 async getAll(): Promise<Array<Application>> {
    return this.applicationModel.find().populate({
      path: 'comments',
      populate: {
        path: 'subComments',
        model: 'SubComment',
        populate: {
          path: 'subComments',
          model: 'SubComment',
          populate: {
            path: 'subComments',
            model: 'SubComment',
          }

        },
      }
    }).populate('ratings').exec();
  }
```

and this is a result. as you see, I have a lot of nested objects with attr SubComment, maybe there is instrument for this multiple populate

```
[
    {
        "_id": "64df6e2bd024862e26834428",
        "title": "Internet Download Manager",
        "viewed": 0,
        "file": [],
        "comments": [
            {
                "_id": "64e08f362ba615f78f5c697f",
                "text": "Internet Download Manager (IDM) is a tool to increase download speeds by up to 5 times, resume or schedule downloads and download streaming videos.",
                "like": 0,
                "dislike": 0,
                "subComments": [
                    {
                        "_id": "64e08f532ba615f78f5c6983",
                        "text": "Yeah really good tool!",
                        "like": 0,
                        "dislike": 0,
                        "subComments": [],
                        "createdAt": "2023-08-19T09:45:55.301Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2023-08-19T09:45:55.301Z",
                        "__v": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "64e08fa32ba615f78f5c6987",
                        "text": "I am also agree with, you this is really good programm)",
                        "like": 0,
                        "dislike": 0,
                        "subComments": [
                            {
                                "_id": "64e0909af6487814b731eb04",
                                "text": "ooo bro, how can you launch it, i found error(",
                                "like": 0,
                                "dislike": 0,
                                "subComments": [
                                    {
                                        "_id": "64e09eee0641c6d2dc9a6e87",
                                        "text": "I am also can't fix that, please if you will find to resole, say me :)",
                                        "like": 0,
                                        "dislike": 0,
                                        "subComments": [
                                            "64e0a59a226c969304641ed8"
                                        ],
                                        "createdAt": "2023-08-19T10:52:30.490Z",
                                        "updatedAt": "2023-08-19T11:20:58.401Z",
                                        "__v": 1
                                    }
                                ],
                                "createdAt": "2023-08-19T09:51:22.398Z",
                                "updatedAt": "2023-08-19T10:52:30.494Z",
                                "__v": 1
                            }
                        ],
                        "createdAt": "2023-08-19T09:47:15.753Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2023-08-19T09:51:22.403Z",
                        "__v": 1
                    }
                ],
                "createdAt": "2023-08-19T09:45:26.015Z",
                "updatedAt": "2023-08-19T09:47:15.755Z",
                "__v": 2
            }
        ],
        "ratings": [
            {
                "_id": "64df6f29d024862e2683443f",
                "rating": 3,
                "createdAt": "2023-08-18T13:16:25.741Z",
                "updatedAt": "2023-08-18T13:16:25.741Z",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ],
        "createdAt": "2023-08-18T13:12:11.222Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-08-19T09:45:26.022Z",
        "__v": 5
    }
]
```

I want to get solution, how to do this nested populate, make shorter.

Answer (score 0):

I was found solution!

```js
private async buildCommentHierarchy(comment: Comment): Promise<Comment> {
    if (comment.subComments && comment.subComments.length > 0) {
      const subCommentsHierarchy = await Promise.all(
        comment.subComments.map(async (subCommentId) => {
          const subComment = await this.subCommentModel.findById(subCommentId).exec();
          if (subComment) {
            const subCommentHierarchy = await this.buildCommentHierarchy(subComment);
            return subCommentHierarchy;
          }
        })
      );

      comment.subComments = subCommentsHierarchy;
    } else {
      comment.subComments = [];
    }

    return comment;
  }

async getAll(): Promise<Application[]> {
const applications = await this.applicationModel.find().lean().exec();

const applicationsWithHierarchy = [];
for (const application of applications) {
  const applicationWithHierarchy: Application = {
    ...application,
    comments: []
  };

  for (const commentId of application.comments) {
    const comment = await this.commentModel.findById(commentId).exec();
    if (comment) {
      const commentHierarchy = await this.buildCommentHierarchy(comment);
      applicationWithHierarchy.comments.push(commentHierarchy);
    }
  }

  applicationsWithHierarchy.push(applicationWithHierarchy);
}

return applicationsWithHierarchy;
  }
```